# Where can I find a client ID for Shutterstock API?

Tags: api, shutterstock

I'm trying to integrate Shutterstock affiliate images in my site.

I found shutterstock documentation and some nice examples that seem to work, but all of them ask me for one 'client id' and 'client secret', two strings with numbers and letters in them.

- I created a new app at developers.shutterstock.com and I get in return:

Consumer Key    xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx

Consumer Secret xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx

Not 'client id' nor 'client secret' here, plus the codes provided have '-' sings in them. Anyway, I tried to replace the working examples 'client id' and 'client secret' codes with this ones. They don't work or get 'not authorized' errors.

- In affiliates.shutterstock.com -> API Access I got: Platform REST Web Services

Account SID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Auth Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Not 'client id' nor 'client secret' here neither. I tried to use this codes too, but don't work or get 'not authorized' errors.

Where can i find those 'client id' and 'client secret' codes?

Answer (score 1):

The consumer key == client id, and consumer secret == client secret. Same things, just different terms. If you're seeing errors with your consumer key feel free to shoot our support an email at apisupport [at] shutterstock.com and we can take a look at it.

Thanks!